# dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bootloader

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 on my sony vaio laptop along with windows8, now ubuntu has been successfully installed and for the First time it showed me both ubuntu and windows8 login options to get in ,but i selected windows 8 after restarting the system it's not showing the ubuntu login ,it's directly  taking me to windows ,so guys please guide me how to fix this issue, it's like when ever i power-on the system it has to show me both the operating systems to select.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you still have Ubuntu iso boot from it and within live environment install boot repair GUI tool and fix GRUB using it it will automatically restore your GRUB and list,